# Samsung mini data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini, water-damage

I'm trying to do a data recovery on a Samsung mini that was dropped in water (I think). The phone won't boot past splash screen and developer access isn't enabled. The best idea I've come up with so far is to do a hard resent and then try to some data recovery software on the phone after it's reset.

I just wanted to try and double-check before I did something stupid?

Many thanks,
Niall

Comment: Samsung has built slot of "mini" devices. Which one are you talking about and how old is the device (or what Android version is installed)?

Comment: Hi, it's the gt-s5570. I'm not sure which android version it is but I'm fairly sure it's stock. Many thanks

Comment: Quite an old phone from 2011. It should run Android 2.3 at least device encryption shouldn't be a problem on this device as it so old. What data are you trying to recover?

Comment: There's a very small possibility that I've some bitcoin in a wallet app on there, probably not much but I thought I'd give it a punt

Comment: flash this zip from recovery mode https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2595705

Comment: Great, I'll give that a try. Many thanks!